# What is input in web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(inputs, hexString, topics);

Tags: solidity, web3js

web3.eth.abi.decodeLog([{

```
type: 'string',
name: 'myString'
```

}
,
{

```
type: 'uint256',
name: 'myNumber',
indexed: true
```

},{

```
type: 'uint8',
name: 'mySmallNumber',
indexed: true
```

}],
'0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000748656c6c6f252100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
['0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f310', '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010']);

> Result {
>       '0': 'Hello%!',
>       '1': '62224',
>       '2': '16',
>       myString: 'Hello%!',
>       myNumber: '62224',
>       mySmallNumber: '16'
>   }

this is decodelog example in "https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-abi.html#decodelog" but i don't know how to find "inputs" parameters.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Related question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99071/how-do-i-determine-the-abi-to-use-for-web3-eth-abi-decodelog/99074

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**inputs** parameter is json object of your event parameters from the smart contract. For example [Chainlink contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x514910771af9ca656af840dff83e8264ecf986ca#code) transfer event is `event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);`. Now if we want to decode this event the input parameter will look like this:

```
[{
    type: 'address',
    name: 'from',
    indexed: true
},{
    type: 'address',
    name: 'to',
    indexed: true
},{
    type: 'uint256',
    name: 'value'
}]
```

Now in order to fully decode the event log we need the rest two parameters which are **hexString** and **topics**. Let's take for example [this random transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xeabe89fa31101320abc382d59a6bcc4022f2ead40e54d14028b496491e94b79a#eventlog) and use it event log data. Example:

```
web3.eth.abi.decodeLog([{
    type: 'address',
    name: 'from',
    indexed: true
},{
    type: 'address',
    name: 'to',
    indexed: true
},{
    type: 'uint256',
    name: 'value'
}],
'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000041b9ece2305db9c00',
['0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef', '0x00000000000000000000000059a5208b32e627891c389ebafc644145224006e8', '0x0000000000000000000000004e2e464420f1392ba08282644feba1bf650e1cc6']);
```

When you execute this code you will see what values have been passed and saved for this event log.

Comment: how can I get event name from transaction receipt event logs?