# How can I extract a wallet address from event data?

Tags: javascript, events, addresses, nodejs

I have a contract that returns event data including the sender's address:

```
event Result(
    address indexed _walletAddress,
    string _name,
    uint256 _amount
)
```

And in my Node.js app I try to capture the address:

```
const address = result[0].topics[1];
```

But for some reason the address contains extra "00000000000000000000000":

```
0x0000000000000000000000001fcda174c13691ef3c13fcee042e0251452c0f8s
```

How can I extract the address in the correct form?

```
0x1fcda174c13691ef3c13fcee042e0251452c0f8s
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: The reason for the extra zeroes is, that ethereum stores everything in 32bytes.
An Ethereum Address is 20bytes in length, hence the extra zeroes in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by using `web3.eth.abi.decodeLog(inputs, hexString, topics);`. The first parameter **inputs** must include the properties of the event from your smart contract, second one **hexString** is the bytecode of the event and the third **topics** is array containing the topics. Read more [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79788/what-is-input-in-web3-eth-abi-decodeloginputs-hexstring-topics/79789#79789).