# get amount of transferred tokens from transaction receipt

Tags: web3js, nodejs

Can someone explain to me how to get the amount of tokens that have been transfered from a transaction receipt? I came across some posts that said I can get it out of the data property from the receipt. But how can I turn the data value into a readable amount of tokens? Some others said it can be found in the logs. The transaction itself has a value of 0 on erc20 token transfers, so I need using the receipt is what I understood so far.

Thank you

Comment: take look at this https://medium.com/linum-labs/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-events-and-logs-on-ethereum-fec84ea7d0a5 it uses the ether library with is a light better version of web3js, i will try to find you a simple example with web3js

Comment: there is also this method https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#decodelog from web3 which can be used to decode the logs.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/79788/what-is-input-in-web3-eth-abi-decodeloginputs-hexstring-topics

Comment: the transfer transaction in ERC20 token emit an event that tell you from which address to which address and how many tokens. that event can be found in the transaction receipt in the "logs" section. when you get the logs you will get data that need to be decoded like the comments above

Comment: there is a difference between the value in the tx and the value in the logs, the value in the transaction is the value of transfered ether which is almost always 0 when you transfer tokens. The value in the logs is the amount of transfer tokens

Comment: read the comments backwards please from here up :) sorry for that

Comment: Yes I know I need to decode the data of the transaction receipt. But how to I decode it is my question now? I got the logs property with the data field, but its a hex value, how can I turn that into an amount of tokens mates?

Comment: Read the other comments :)